# Error while installing angular CLI

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I am facing this **timedout error** while installing **angularCLI** on a corporate network. Below is my error log:

```
C:\Users\A0724458>npm install -g @angular/cli
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "@angular/cli"
npm ERR! node v6.11.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10
npm ERR! code ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! errno ETIMEDOUT
npm ERR! syscall connect

npm ERR! network connect ETIMEDOUT 151.101.8.162:443
npm ERR! network This is most likely not a problem with npm itself
npm ERR! network and is related to network connectivity.
npm ERR! network In most cases you are behind a proxy or have bad network settings.
npm ERR! network
npm ERR! network If you are behind a proxy, please make sure that the
npm ERR! network 'proxy' config is set properly.  See: 'npm help config'

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\A0724458\npm-debug.log
```

Could someone help me sort this out?

Comment: Are you working behind a proxy server?

Comment: What is your npm version ?

Answer (score 0):

If you are working behind a proxy server, you need to configure it. Run the following in the command line.

```
npm config set proxy <your proxy server>
npm config set https-proxy <your proxy server>
```

Also you might need to set the property `strict-ssl` to `false`.

```
npm config set strict-ssl false
```

Comment: I executed this now im getting the following error,

Comment: npm ERR! registry error parsing json
npm ERR! Windows_NT 6.1.7601
npm ERR! argv "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\node.exe" "C:\\Program Files\\nodejs\\
node_modules\\npm\\bin\\npm-cli.js" "install" "-g" "@angular/cli"
npm ERR! node v6.11.2
npm ERR! npm  v3.10.10

npm ERR! Unexpected token F in JSON at position 4
npm ERR! 404 File Not Found
npm ERR!
npm ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
npm ERR!     <https://github.com/npm/npm/issues>

npm ERR! Please include the following file with any support request:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\A0724458\npm-debug.log

Comment: I am also facing similar issue while my teammate who is in same network could install successfully. Can still it be proxy issue? I have also added npmrc file in c/user/myusername path